# ajax onload page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

**Мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы, отправлялся этот ajax запрос, не при клике, а именно страница открылась и тут же отправился мой ajax запрос, как это можно сделать?**

```
   <body onload="myFunction()">

   function myFunction() {

    }
    $(document).ready(myFunction())
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{route('covid.getResult')}}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                order_id: '{{$order_id ?? ''}}',
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                hash: '{{$hash ?? ''}}'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.code == 200) {

                    alert("YES")

                } else {
                    alert("NO")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Вынесите объявление `function myFunction() { ...}` ДО `$(document).ready` после чего вызывайте ее  либо на `onLoad`, либо в `$(document).ready( myFunction() );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{route('covid.getResult')}}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                order_id: '{{$order_id ?? ''}}',
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                hash: '{{$hash ?? ''}}'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.code == 200) {

                    alert("YES")

                } else {
                    alert("NO")
                }
            }
        });
}

$(document).ready( myFunction() );
```

Comment: `.ready( myFunction() )` в таком виде `myFunction` выполнится до того, как произойдет вызов `document.ready`

Comment: В таком виде он вообще не выполнится. Конечно же правильный синтаксис `$(document).ready(function(){ myFunction(); });`, но я думаю автор вопроса это прекрасно знает

Comment: выполнится, просто потому, что ты сам вызываешь эту функцию. Проблема тут не в синтаксисе, а в том, когда должна запускаться функция.

Comment: @Grundy ,  если четсно не понял, что Вы этим хотели сказать. От слова `вообще`. Если Вы про то, что лучше вызывать в `onLoad` чем в `document.ready` - читайте разницу между этими методами, например вот тут `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395780/difference-between-onload-and-ready`

Comment: ты вызываешь функцию непосредственно перед передачей в качестве параметра `myFunction()`, это будет работать неожиданно для пользователя, которых хотел запустить ее, по событию `onload`.

Comment: @Grundy еще раз прочитайте текст задачи, а потом почитайте различие между `onLoad` и `$(document).ready()` - ссылку выше я привел. И давайте закончим нашу с Вами беседу - она становится бессмысленной и не имеющей отношения к задаче. Если Вы считаете, что данный мною ответ неверный - ставьте соответствующую оценку.

Comment: да, твой ответ плохой - нет пояснений что поменялось, некорректное использование `document.ready`. Не понял причем тут различие `onLoad` и `ready` - если в ответе ты руками вызываешь функцию, не передавая никакой `callback`.